# Download Viber photos daily using python?

Tags: python, viber

I have to download and save photos sent on Viber each day because of a project and I would like to automate it. I'm a little familiar with python but I am a beginner. Is that possible to download photos sent on Viber by date, using python?

I thought maybe some kind of API could help. I found some similar topics on the internet but that was about downloading messages.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should contact Viber and ask them if they have an API you could use

Comment: Just write "Viber API" to Google and you get their API documentation as the first result: https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api